# Mongo aggregate query for facets navigation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `products` with documents (products) like this (relevant code only):

```
{ "_id": "prod1", ... "colors": ["red","blue"], "size": ["S", "M"], ...}
{ "_id": "prod2", ... "colors": ["red","green"], "size": ["S", "XL"], ...}
{ "_id": "prod3", ... "colors": ["yellow","blue"], "size": ["XL", "XXL"], ...}
```

I would like to offer the user only the available selection, as a faceted search, like the name of the option and the number of options available.

colors:

```
red 2
blue 2
green 1
yellow 1
```

sizes:

```
S 2
M 1
XL 2
XXL 1
```

If I had to do it in SQL, I would probably have to run a query for each facet group.

```
SELECT colors, count(*) AS number FROM products GROUP BY colors
```

than the second query

```
SELECT size, count(*) AS number FROM test GROUP BY sizes
```

If somebody chose color "red", than I would probably have to add to each query the "WHERE" clause:

```
WHERE colors = 'red'
```

Could somebody more experienced than me, help me with this example in MongoDB? Do I have to run two queries or is there something that I am missing and it could be done in one query? I assume I will have a great number of products. Any help appreciated. Especially if there are any tricks to speed it up. I would like to get it right from the beginning, hence asking the question. Thanks.

Comment: what version of MongoDB are you on?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution for your query with MongoDB aggregation. Below is my dummy collection.

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("584b82055855b8ea7ea29d65"),
        "colors" : [ 
            "Red", 
            "Yellow"
        ],
        "size" : [ 
            "S", 
            "M"
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("584b82185855b8ea7ea29d66"),
        "colors" : [ 
            "Red", 
            "Orange"
        ],
        "size" : [ 
            "S", 
            "XL"
        ]
    }
.
.
```

After running below query.

```
    db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$colors"},
    {$group : {
        _id : "$colors",
        "sum": {$sum : 1}
    }},
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            "color":"$_id",
            "count":"$sum"
        }
    }
])
```

Then the output is :

```
{
    "color" : "Green",
    "count" : 2
}
{
    "color" : "Orange",
    "count" : 1
}
{
    "color" : "Yellow",
    "count" : 2
}
{
    "color" : "Red",
    "count" : 2
}
```

If you want to find sum only for **Red** Color then below query for this

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$colors"},
    {$match : {"colors":"Red"}},
    {$group : {
        _id : "$colors",
        "sum": {$sum : 1}
    }},
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            "color":"$_id",
            "count":"$sum"
        }
    }
])
```

The output of above query is :

```
{
    "color" : "Red",
    "count" : 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The magic of $unwind

When you need to count something that's into an array you have to unwind it first. Take a look at this:

```
db.products.aggregate([ { $unwind : "$colors" }] )
```

It generates a row per item of the array.

Once you unwind it you can pipe the next group:

```
db.products.aggregate([ 
{ $unwind : "$colors" }, 
{$group: { _id : "$colors", total_colors : { $sum : 1} } } 
] )
```

Name the aggregated field as you wish :) The same can be done with the sizes grouped as you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.entry.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$size" },
{$group: { "_id" : "$size", count : { $sum : 1 } } }
]).pretty()
```

Hope this helps, you can customize as you wish for the 'count' field and $unwind definition:

*Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.*

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 1):

Faceted search is implemented in version 3.4 of MongoDB data base.

```
{ $facet:
   {
      <outputField1>: [ <stage1>, <stage2>, ... ],
      <outputField2>: [ <stage1>, <stage2>, ... ],
      ...

   }
}
```

Here is [link to documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

Answer (score 0):

- Using **Faceted search**, this is how you can achieve your desire result.
- This is more readable and performant than using multiple `$group` operator.

```js
    db.products.aggregate([{
                             $facet:{
                                 colors: [{ $unwind: "$colors" },{ $sortByCount: "$colors" }],
                                 sizes: [{ $unwind: "$sizes" },{ $sortByCount: "$sizes" }]
                             }
                           } 
                         ]);
```

checkout [$facet operator in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)